# Is there any use case for an anonymous OCaml structure

Tags: module, ocaml

The OCaml manual, Chapter 2, says

> a structure and is introduced by the struct…end construct, which contains an arbitrary sequence of definitions. The structure is usually given a name with the module binding.

Is there any use case for the creating a struct and not giving it a module name.
If not, then we always use

```
module Name =
  struct
    ...
  end
```

and so the struct keyword seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible and even common (in my code at least) to use nameless structures. One example:

```
module MyStrSet =
   Set.Make(struct type t = string let compare a b = compare b a end)
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand slightly on Jeffrey's answer, an OCaml functor maps a module to another module. It doesn't care about the module's *name*.

Consider the following trivial example.

```
module type SIG =
sig
  val x : int
end

module A (B : SIG) =
struct
  let y = B.x * 2
end
```

I've defined a functor `A` which takes a module `B` that fulfills the module type `SIG`.  Now, I could define a module `Twenty_one` that supplies an `x` value of `21`, and then give that to the functor `A` to create module `C`.

```
module Twenty_one = 
struct
  let x = 21
end

module C = A (Twenty_one)
```

Or I could directly use an anonymous structure.

```
module C = A (struct let x = 21 end)
```

We don't even *need* to name `SIG`.

```
module A (B : sig val x : int end) =
struct
  let y = B.x * 2
end

module C = A (struct let x = 21 end)
```

Strongly into opinion territory, but you may *want* to give these things names in your code, if it aids with reuse and expressivess.

E.g.

```
module Int =
struct
  type t = int
  let compare = compare
end

module Int_map = Map.Make (Int)
```

Vs.

```
module Int_map = Map.Make (struct type t = int let compare = compare end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do with an anonymous structure, that's more relevant to recent (as of 4.08.0) OCaml, is the ability to use `open` with it, for a syntactically-cheap way to hide names in your namespace (until you write an interface file anyway):

```ml
open struct
  type hidden_type = string
  let hidden_name = 42
end
```

This feature is called generalized-open, and the relevant manual page for it is [here](https://ocaml.org/manual/generalizedopens.html#start-section).